# JPA @ManyToMany relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have a case with Many to Many relationship

Following is the Book class with `isbn` as unique identifier

```js
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -4643154384069203197L;

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;
  
@Column(name = "isbn")
private String isbn;
  
  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "book_author", 
joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "bookId",      referencedColumnName = "id") }, 
inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "authorId", referencedColumnName = "id") })
private Set<Author> authors = new HashSet<>();
  
// Getters and setters
// hashcode and equals using only isbn
```

Following is the Author class with `email` as unique identifier

```js
@Entity
@Table(name = "author")
public class Author implements Serializable{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6907306347041383886L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "book")
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authors")
    private Set<Book> books =  new HashSet<>();

    //getters and setters
    // hashcode and equals using only "email"
```

I am able to achieve unique Book, as the Set checks the `isbn` and removes all the duplicates.
Since every Book can have many authors and vice versa I tried with Many to Many rekationship.

The problem comes with the unique `email`, Every book has an individual authors Set. How can I achevie author with unique email in the author table?

Help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Email is a field in Author. So it should be simply findByEmail in your jpaRepository. And for every author you will get one email only. Why confusion?

Comment: So, do you want to me check DB if there is an author with same email?, before inserting? @AjayKumar

Comment: Yes. You can write a validator like this: https://github.com/ajkr195/springbootrocks/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spring/boot/rocks/validator/AppUserAddValidator.java

Answer (score 0):

Change you `@Column(name="email")` into `@Column(unique = true)`

`name="email"`is redundant since by default it will grab the name of the attribute which is anyways email

Comment: I tried ```unique = true ``` it gives unique contraint violation while saving the Book entity

Comment: make sure all your emails are unique and then there wont be any violation - wasnt unique emails what you wanted?

Comment: What if two Books have same author (email)?

Comment: that wont trigger any issues because they both will be referencing the same row in the authors table (which has only unique emails). I feel like you need to spend some time understanding how database tables work and reference each other... looks for some youtube videos on relational databases